# How to print an array list (that's using char) in a JTextArea?

Tags: java, arraylist, char, jtextarea

Okay, so I have to make a game for school that's called "Angry Tanks" it's basically a simpler version of Angry Birds. 
We have to read in a textfile to use as a landscape for our game, this text file contais spaces and hashtags, the hastags represent the land.
The file has bean read and inserted into an arraylist, there is a public method calles getLandscapeFromFile().

I am trying to print the landscape into a JTextArea called textArea, using a loop that replaces all the hashtags with an image. Am I supposed to use a textArea or should another panel be used?

This is the code I've tried but doesn't work:

```
for (int i = 0; i < Landscape.getLandscapeFromFile().size(); i++) {
            for (char[] c : Landscape.getLandscapeFromFile()) {
                textArea.append(String.valueOf(c[i]));
}
}
```

I've been trying all sort of stuff, but nothing seems to work...
And by the way, I'm not very good at Java, this is only my first year studying IT.

Comment: What is the return type of geLandscapeFromFile() ?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is in your second loop

You select `i` char of word

```
for (char[] c : Landscape.getLandscapeFromFile()) {
        textArea.append(String.valueOf(c[i]));
    }
```

You probably wonted to write each character of that array.

```
for (char[] c : Landscape.getLandscapeFromFile()) {
    textArea.append(String.valueOf(c));
}
```

As you task is to write the content form File to textArea you should do this.

TIP: You should avoid to access the loading method twice as it can time consuming user a local variable.

```
List<char[]> landscapes = Landscape.getLandscapeFromFile(); //Read once 

for(char[] landscape : landscapes) {//Iterate through all landscapes
    stextArea.append(new String(landscape)); //Create new String for char array
}
```

Comment: The snippet in the second grey box and the snippet in the third grey box are exactly equivalent; because (i) in the second grey box, `getLandscapeFromFile` is called only once, and (ii) `String.valueOf(c)` just calls `new String(c)` if `c` is a `char[]`.  Therefore, your "TIP" is a red herring and adds nothing to an otherwise excellent answer.

Comment: The tip refer to single usage of method `getLandscapeFormFile()`. ;-)

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `StringBuilder`:

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

for (int i = 0; i < Landscape.getLandscapeFromFile().size(); i++) {
    for (char[] c : Landscape.getLandscapeFromFile()) {
        sb.append(String.valueOf(c));
    }
}

textArea.setText(sb.toString());
```

Comment: I still get a blank textarea. :(

Comment: Try printing `sb.toString()` before setting the text to `textArea`. If it is not empty, there is another problem. Maybe an attributes one.

Comment: @AmyLinck what is `getLandscapeFromFile()` returning?